# php function json_encode returns false?

Tags: json

I got following message from the developer:

> When the data array is too long, then php function json_encode returns false.

The server uses php `5.6.21`, apache `2.2.15`. I am not sure there is a server configuration or something that prevents this happening from server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He may mean too deep rather than too long.

The default maximum depth of nested arrays for json_encode is 512.  You can override this with the 3rd parameter to json_encode; e.g. `$json = json_encode($thing, 0, 1024);` to set it to 1024.

Comment: Sorry. Can you tell me where to put that parameter such like php.ini?

Comment: I did tell you.  It's the 3rd parameter (argument) to the `json_encode()` function; the last one.  The default is 512, if you do not specify a value.

Comment: Sorry. I am not an expert on programming so it seems like it should be done in scripts not server configuration. Is that right?

Comment: It is a change to the PHP code, where the `json_encode()` function is being called.  This is not expert level, it's basic.  The developer you mentioned should be able to fix it, if you can't.

Comment: They said their script doesn't have a depth more than 5 so it's not a valid point to extend to 1024. What else I should look at from server side?